# How to calculate the difference of two expected values with different distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

I know that two random variables with the same distribution is $E_{p}(X+Y) = E_{p}(X) + E_{p}(Y)$. I am now trying to solve a problem which involves calculating the difference of two expected values of the same random variables but with different distributions.
$$
E_{p_1(X)}[{f(x)}] - E_{p_2(X)}[{f(x)}]
$$
where $x \in X$. The two expected values are expected over the same functions with different distributions. I think the this value might be related to its KL divergence $KL(p_1(X)||p_2(X))$ since the only thing here influencing this value are the two distributions. But I don't know how to prove it. Thank you for the help if someone knows what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Expectation is linear, so for any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ (regardless of their distribution or correlation) and constants $a$ and $b$, it is true that $E(aX + bY) = aE(X) + bE(Y)$. So setting $a = 1, b = -1$ gives $E(X) - E(Y) = E(X - Y)$. This is true even if $Y = g(X)$ for some function (although it is *not* true in general that $E(g(Y)) = g(E(Y))$).